# Reference for infinite exponentiation

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, reference-request, book-recommendation, tetration

I'm trying to find a *book* or a *paper* on infinite exponentiation: more precisely, it should be proving its *full* interval of convergence on the positive real line, i.e. if $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then $x^{x^{x^\cdots}}$ converges if and only if $e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}$.

While I didn't manage to find any books about it, there are these two papers from The American Mathematical Monthly:

1. [Knoebel's *Exponentials Reiterated*](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/exponentials-reiterated-0)
2. [Mitchelmore's *A Matter of Definition*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319223?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1)

Also, there's this paper on arXiv:

3. [Moroni's *The strange properties of the infinite power tower*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05559)

*Every one of them is problematic.*

Paper #1 [doesn't make sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005111/given-zzx-x-estimate-fracdxdz) towards the end of page 242 and is rather incomprehensible there.

Paper #2 shows only the convergence for $1\le x\le e^{1/e}$ and the conclusion is

> DEFINITION. For all real $x$ such that $0\le x\le e^{1/e}$, $x^{x^{x^\cdots}}$ is the real solution for $t$ of the equation $x^t=t$, and in case this equation has two solutions, then the lesser one.

That is not satisfactory at all.

Paper #3 makes an incorrect assumption on page 15, which is the following:

> If the first first derivative is $|z'(y_1^*)|\lt 1$ (that is $-1\le z'(y_1^*)\lt 0$...

There shouldn't be $-1\le$ but $-1\lt$, the author probably does so to avoid the analysis of the case when $x=e^{-e}$, but at the same time he further in the text states that the infinite tetration for $x=e^{-e}$ is convergent. So that one is incomplete.

Comment: If you only want proofs of the bounds for convergence for infinite tetration, I believe there are proofs in a pair of questions here on mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: @Mark S. I know that, but I want to reference a proof. It will be better if it is a book or a paper.

Comment: See the comment I feel obliged to do, as a rather experienced man, some days ago to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3999820)

Comment: @JeanMarie "Tetration has no interest in pure mathematics"? I think it has interest on its own. The research on it gives me headache though... The topic is very obscure.

Comment: If I were writing a paper for a journal and I needed to cite the convergence interval, I'd try looking for books/papers myself but would be comfortable just citing MSE proofs in the end since this is sort of a folklore result. Can you add the context as to why you need a book or a paper in particular?

Comment: @MarkS. Well, if this is really that *folklore* result, then books/papers aren't hopefully needed.

Comment: Euler, Eisenstein should be good search-tokens. I think it was discussed in an exchange between the two people, but don't have a link at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ioannis Galidakis' [*A Collection of References For Infinite Exponentials and Tetration*](https://ingalidakis.com/math/IERefs.html), see items #7, 19, 88, 110, 111, 166. See also [*On the Convergence of Iterated Exponentiation—I*](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/18-4/creutz.pdf) by Creutz/Sternheimer (1980) and [*On* ${x^{x^{x^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{\cdot}}}}}}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Throughout+this+note%2C+we+will+always+associate%22) by Louis A. Talman (written in 1999, I think).

Comment: Anderson's paper (item #7) states in the introduction that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct positive numbers such that $x^x=y^y$, then we say the set $\{x,y\}$ is a *Bernoulli pair*. This is inconsistent with the rest of the text. I think that *Bernoulli pairs* should be the solutions of $x^y=y^x$ instead.

Comment: @1mik1: Yes, I agree. This is clearly a typo, since $x^x = y^y$ for values of $x$ and $y$ greater than $1/e = 0.367879\ldots$ implies $x=y,$ and thus this would not a useful definition. The reason this equality implies $x=y$ is that the function $f:(\frac{1}{e},\infty) \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(t) = t^t$ is strictly increasing (because [its derivative is greater than zero when $\ln t + 1 > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72426/derivative-of-xx)), and thus injective, and hence for these values of $x$ and $y$ we have $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x=y.$